# Android to Web server issue

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, wamp

I have done application in android. It is application to create a account and login user screen to web sever. When it run in eclipse it register a account & sign in but when it is install in my phone, & will not register, login a user. Is there any speed performance or data connection problem.?? How to improve speed android application to web server?

It is application is JSON parser DefaultHttpClient with PHP files connect in webserver. Please help me why it is not connected to my mobile?

The userl is http://mywebapp.com/TestAndroid/check.php

Thanks Nitin

Comment: It would be better if you attach the device to the system and read the logs. Could be that the device is not able to connect to the web url you might have given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you wrote the app you should be able to use logcat to understand what's happening, maybe add more temporary log statements to your code to help understand what is happening.